# How is it that INTERNET_SCHEME_HTTPS is defined differently in two header files?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, winapi

Say, if I include `Winhttp.h` the `INTERNET_SCHEME_HTTPS` is defined as `2`:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh707320(v=vs.85).aspx

but if I include `Wininet.h`, it is defined as `4`:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385149(v=vs.85).aspx

So which one is it?

Comment: One's a macro definition and the other is an enumeration, so they can't really coexist.  I suppose the only clean workaround is to avoid using WinINet and WinHTTP in the same module, though if you really had to you could `#undef` the macro and replace it with one of your own.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is both are valid.  It depends on what you're using, WinINet, or WinHTTP.

To quote from the [WinINet vs. WinHTTP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh227298%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on MSDN:

> With a few exceptions, WinINet is a superset of WinHTTP. When selecting between the two, you should use WinINet, unless you plan to run within a service or service-like process that requires impersonation and session isolation.

In short, the two interfaces are incompatible because they don't have to be compatible. The two are mutually-exclusive.

If you're in a situation where for some reason you need both, either separate the implementations into separate modules, or as suggested in comments by Harry Johnston, and IInspectable, save the macro using [`#pragma push_macro`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/2bs04eza.aspx) and then `#undef` it.

Comment: Thou shalt never `#undef` a macro, without first saving it using [#pragma push_macro](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/2bs04eza.aspx). This is the generic solution to solving pretty much all preprocessor symbol clashes.

Comment: @IInspectable - Added.  I shouldn't take it for granted that people will preserve things before overwriting.